# What is a good way to draw Dynkin diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, svg, feynmf

I'm about to start writing something up which includes a fair number of [Dynkin diagrams](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DynkinDiagram.html), and I can think of several ways of going about it:

- Just draw the darn things in, *e.g.,* [InkScape](http://www.inkscape.org/), and include the graphics in the standard way.
- Hack them together using the `picture` environment or tikz, as [this person](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~njschwar/latex.shtml) suggests.
- Abuse the [feynmf](http://xml.web.cern.ch/XML/textproc/feynmf.html) package, possibly with defining new kinds of "propagator" lines.

Anybody have experience with this sort of task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would not recommend abusing the feynmf package.  In the past I have used the picture environment (with the `eepic` package) to do precisely this.

Table 6.2 in page 185 of [these lecture notes](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/EDC.pdf) (PDF file), I typeset the Dynkin diagrams using the picture environment.  I'm happy to make the code available.  Here's a sample for the $A_n$ Dynkin diagram:

```
\begin{picture}(50,7)
\multiput(5,1)(10,0){5}{\circle{2}}
\multiputlist(10,1)(10,0)%
{{\line(1,0){8}},{\line(1,0){8}},{$\cdots$},{\line(1,0){8}}}
\multiputlist(5,3)(10,0){$\scriptscriptstyle 1$,%
$\scriptscriptstyle 2$,$\scriptscriptstyle 3$,%
$\scriptscriptstyle \ell{-}1$,$\scriptscriptstyle \ell$}
\end{picture}
```

The diagram is decorated with a labelling of the nodes, by the way.

Comment: Actually, this only uses the `epic` package, not the `eepic` package.

Answer (score 24):

Try the [dynkin-diagrams](https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams) package from CTAN.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\def\row#1/#2!{#1_{\IfStrEq{#2}{}{n}{#2}} & \dynkin{#1}{#2}\\}
\newcommand{\tble}[1]{
   \renewcommand*\do[1]{\row##1!}
   \[
      \begin{array}{ll}\docsvlist{#1}\end{array}
   \]
}
\begin{document}
\tble{A/{},B/{},C/{},D/{},E/6,E/7,E/8,F/4,G/2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have two additional suggestions:

- Use the [Xy-pic](http://tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) package. I find easier than tikz or feynmf.
- Or you can find a paper on the arxiv which has some Dynkin diagrams and see what the authors have done.

Answer (score 6):

I typically use tikz. I like tikz because I find it relatively straight-forward. Also, because my interest is in representation theory and quivers I have to create many other diagrams beyond Dynkin diagrams and tikz allows me to use a single language to create all of them and the resulting graphics have a consistent style (arrow heads, line thickness, etc).

Comment: I like tikz a lot, too. There's a great site that has a lot of examples, though no Dynkin Diagrams (yet!): http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/