# How can I replicate affine Dynkin diagrams in Kac's textbook?

Tags: diagrams

I'm sorry for asking a similar question to [this tex.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409/what-is-a-good-way-to-draw-dynkin-diagrams-in-latex), but my motivation is different.

I'd like to replicate the affine Dynkin diagrams as in Kac's textbook, see pp. 53, 54 and 55 of the third edition. Here are links to the pages in Google Books: [p. 53](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=kuEjSb9teJwC&pg=PA53#v=onepage), [p. 54](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=kuEjSb9teJwC&pg=PA54#v=onepage) and [p. 55](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=kuEjSb9teJwC&pg=PA55#v=onepage).

Judging from the fonts used, he or the typesetter used simple TeX symbols as much as possible, including the double-lined arrows, `\Leftarrow` etc., instead of using generic diagramming packages. How can I do that?

It's a stupid question, not applicable to drawing generic diagrams, but I liked Kac's "minimalism". Also, his textbook is like a Bible in this field of mathematics, so I just want to follow his example, even in typesetting affine Dynkin diagrams!

Thanks in advance.

---

(Update) Thanks to the answers of all of you, I put the following diagrams in my paper:

[image: affine Dynkin diagrams]

see page 9 of [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.0531).

Comment: This looks like a dupe to me - would vote to close if I were not a mod

Comment: Sorry for looking like a dupe, but I **really** want to reproduce the Table in this textbook: http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=kuEjSb9teJwC&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase your question. I guess the hard part is how to draw triple and quadruple arrows? At least, that is the only thing I don't know by heart how to achieve it in TikZ and I can't find anything about it. The rest is just regular Dynkin stuff, which boils down to drawing graphs.

Comment: I guess when Kac's book was written pgf/TikZ was not available; shouldn't there be an elementary way? I like the way Kac used the standard arrows which is part of math fonts, not the generated arrows in XyPic or pgf. The triple arrow comes with AMSTeX, it's called `\Lleftarrow` and `\Rrightarrow`.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: I disagree about the duplication.  @Yuji's diagrams are more complicated the "accepted" answer in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: I would say if the OP already points out the possible duplicate, then it's quite probable that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @Matthew: My point was that the question is a dupe: whether the original was answered or not does not affect the question side of things, as I understand it. Both are asking essentially 'how to draw a variety of Dynkin diagram in LaTeX'.

Comment: That's not my essential point; my point is to reproduce what Kac has in his textbook. I changed the title of the question after @Joseph Wright gave me the comment. Indeed I didn't express my intent correctly.

Comment: @Yuji: How exact do you want the replication to be?  Looking at the pictures, I can guess a few ways to do it but all would probably be out by a little bit.  In addition, the spacing is a little inconsistent (particularly with regard to the vertical and horizontal spacing, say in the E_8 diagram), so I would want to fix that.  Would that be allowed?

Comment: @Andrew: I'm fine with that. If the spacing is nicer, that would be even better. I really liked Kac's "minimalism", in the sense that he used only what's simply available in AMSTeX, like `\circ`, `\cdots`, standard minus sign, and `\Leftarrow`. So I'd like to replicate that.

Comment: Is your desire to replicate Kac's style based on the formatting or the code?  That is, do you want it to *look* like you just used the standard commands, or do you want to actually use them?  If the former, I would suggest using TikZ, as one of its features is that it can use TeX arrowheads, fonts, etc., and it's designed for layout.

Comment: @Antal, it's OK if it looks the same; but I'm also interested how he or the typesetter did it long time ago when it was published.

Comment: The dynkin-diagrams package on CTAN has a Kac option, which comes close to the style you are looking for. The arrows are not quite in the right style, but otherwise it looks pretty close.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

And now let me show you the *right* way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[paperheight=40cm,scale=.97]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzset{node distance=2em, ch/.style={circle,draw,on chain,inner sep=2pt},chj/.style={ch,join},every path/.style={shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt},line width=1pt,baseline=-1ex}

\newcommand{\alabel}[1]{%
  \(\alpha_{\mathrlap{#1}}\)
}

\newcommand{\mlabel}[1]{%
  \(#1\)
}

\let\dlabel=\alabel
\let\ulabel=\mlabel

\newcommand{\dnode}[2][chj]{%
\node[#1,label={below:\dlabel{#2}}] {};
}

\newcommand{\dnodea}[3][chj]{%
\dnode[#1,label={above:\ulabel{#2}}]{#3}
}

\newcommand{\dnodeanj}[2]{%
\dnodea[ch]{#1}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\dnodenj}[1]{%
\dnode[ch]{#1}
}

\newcommand{\dnodebr}[1]{%
\node[chj,label={below right:\dlabel{#1}}] {};
}

\newcommand{\dnoder}[2][chj]{%
\node[#1,label={right:\dlabel{#2}}] {};
}

\newcommand{\dydots}{%
\node[chj,draw=none,inner sep=1pt] {\dots};
}

\newcommand{\QRightarrow}{%
\begingroup
\tikzset{every path/.style={}}%
\tikz \draw (0,3pt) -- ++(1em,0) (0,1pt) -- ++(1em+1pt,0) (0,-1pt) -- ++(1em+1pt,0) (0,-3pt) -- ++(1em,0) (1em-1pt,5pt) to[out=-75,in=135] (1em+2pt,0) to[out=-135,in=75] (1em-1pt,-5pt);
\endgroup
}

\newcommand{\QLeftarrow}{%
\begingroup
\tikz
\draw[shorten >=0pt,shorten <=0pt] (0,3pt) -- ++(-1em,0) (0,1pt) -- ++(-1em-1pt,0) (0,-1pt) -- ++(-1em-1pt,0) (0,-3pt) -- ++(-1em,0) (-1em+1pt,5pt) to[out=-105,in=45] (-1em-2pt,0) to[out=-45,in=105] (-1em+1pt,-5pt);
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
A_l &&& 
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dydots
\dnode{l-1}
\dnode{l}
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(l+1) \\
%
B_l &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dydots
\dnode{l-1}
\dnodenj{l}
\path (chain-4) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(2) \\
%
C_l &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dydots
\dnode{l-1}
\dnodenj{l}
\path (chain-4) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(2) \\
%
D_l &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\node[chj,draw=none] {\dots};
\dnode{l-2}
\dnode{l-1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-4);
\dnodebr{l}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(4) \\
%
E_6 &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyni in {1,...,5} {
\dnode{\dyni}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin (chain-3);
\dnodebr{6}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(3) \\
%
E_7 &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyni in {1,...,6} {
\dnode{\dyni}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin (chain-3);
\dnodebr{7}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(2) \\
%
E_8 &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyni in {1,...,7} {
\dnode{\dyni}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin (chain-5);
\dnodebr{8}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(1) \\
%
F_4 &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dnodenj{3}
\dnode{4}
\path (chain-2) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
&&
(1) \\
%
G_2 &&&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodenj{1}
\dnodenj{2}
\path (chain-1) -- node {\(\Rrightarrow\)} (chain-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\let\dlabel=\mlabel

\begin{align*}
&A_1^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodenj{1}
\dnodenj{1}
\path (chain-1) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Longleftrightarrow\)} (chain-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&A_l^{(1)} (l \ge 2) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain,node distance=1ex and 2em]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{1}
\dydots
\dnode{1}
\dnode{1}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-3);
\node[ch,join=with chain-1,join=with chain-5,label={[inner sep=1pt]10:\(1\)}] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&B_l^{(1)} (l \ge 3) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dnode{2}
\dydots
\dnode{2}
\dnodenj{2}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-2);
\dnodebr{1}
\end{scope}
\path (chain-5) -- node{\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&C_l^{(1)} (l \ge 2) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodenj{1}
\dnodenj{2}
\dydots
\dnode{2}
\dnodenj{1}
\path (chain-1) -- node{\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-2);
\path (chain-4) -- node{\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&D_l^{(1)} (l \ge 4) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dnode{2}
\dydots
\dnode{2}
\dnode{1}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-2);
\dnodebr{1};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br2 going above]
\chainin(chain-5);
\dnodebr{1};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&G_2^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dnodenj{3}
\path (chain-2) -- node{\(\Rrightarrow\)} (chain-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&F_4^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnode{1}
\dnode{2}
\dnode{3}
\dnodenj{4}
\dnode{2}
\path (chain-3) -- node[anchor=mid]{\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&E_6^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyi in {1,2,3,2,1} {
\dnode{\dyi}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-3);
\dnodebr{2}
\dnodebr{1}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&E_7^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyi in {1,2,3,4,3,2,1} {
\dnode{\dyi}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-4);
\dnodebr{2}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&E_8^{(1)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\foreach \dyi in {1,2,3,4,5,6,4,2} {
\dnode{\dyi}
}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-6);
\dnodebr{3}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\let\dlabel=\alabel

\begin{align*}
&A_2^{(2)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodeanj{2}{0}
\dnodeanj{1}{1}
\path (chain-1) -- node {\QLeftarrow} (chain-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&A_{2l}^{(2)} (l \ge 2) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodeanj{2}{0}
\dnodeanj{2}{1}
\dydots
\dnodea{2}{l-1}
\dnodea{1}{l}
\path (chain-1) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&A_{2l-1}^{(2)} (l \ge 3) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\dnodea{1}{1}
\node[chj,label={below:\dlabel{2}},label={[inner sep=1pt]above right:\mlabel{2}}] {};
\dnodea{2}{3}
\dydots
\dnodea{2}{l-1}
\dnodeanj{1}{l}
\path (chain-5) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-6);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=br going above]
\chainin(chain-2);
\node[chj,label={below left:\dlabel{0}},label={[inner sep=1pt]above right:\mlabel{1}}] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&D_{l+1}^{(2)} (l \ge 2) &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodea{1}{1}
\dnodeanj{1}{1}
\dydots
\dnodea{1}{l-1}
\dnodeanj{1}{l}
\path (chain-1) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-2);
\path (chain-4) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Rightarrow\)} (chain-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
%
&E_6^{(2)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodea{1}{0}
\dnodea{2}{1}
\dnodea{3}{2}
\dnodeanj{2}{3}
\dnodea{1}{4}
\path (chain-3) -- node[anchor=mid] {\(\Leftarrow\)} (chain-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&D_4^{(3)} &&
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
\dnodea{1}{0}
\dnodea{2}{1}
\dnodeanj{1}{2}
\path (chain-2) -- node {\(\Lleftarrow\)} (chain-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

I'm sure that there are cleaner ways to do this, and optimisations (though, for the record, some of my experiments with the `chains` library didn't work correctly - indeed, I couldn't get some of the examples in the manual to compile).  I tried to get it as close to the book as I could, whilst looking for a slightly more expansive and "cleaner" style (at least, as far as the preview in Google docs goes).

One of these days I'll learn what these diagrams actually mean ...

Packages loaded:

- `geometry`: just to get the whole lot on one page
- `amssymb`: to get the triple arrows and the left-right double arrow
- `mathtools`: to get the `mathrlap` command as I preferred the labels centred on the `\alpha` rather than on the whole label.
- `tikz`: to do the actual diagram
- `chains`: to do the automatic placement of the nodes

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you very much for the TeX code. Is it OK for me to include them into the paper on this subject? Well I don't know whether and when it ever becomes complete, though. They look beautiful!

Comment: @Yuji: Of course it's okay - everything posted here is available under a Creative Commons license (see foot of page for exact details of what you have to do - if it's not clear, ask a question about it on meta).  Not sure I understand what you mean by "complete" though - unless you're referring to the paper.  Incidentally, when cut-and-pasting, be ware that my code sets up some global TikZ defaults which - if you have other diagrams - you might want to make local.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the first page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A_l &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \dotsb - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_{l-1}}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_l}}{\circ} && (l+1) \\
%
B_l &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \dotsb - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_{l-1}}}{\circ} \Rightarrow \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_l}}{\circ} && (2) \\
%
C_l &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \dotsb - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_{l-1}}}{\circ} \Leftarrow \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_l}}{\circ} && (2) \\
%
D_l &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \dotsb - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_{l-2}}}{\overset{\overset{\textstyle\circ_{\mathrlap{\alpha_l}}}{\textstyle\vert}}{\circ}} \,-\, \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_{l-1}}}{\circ} && (4) \\
%
E_6 &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_3}}{\overset{\overset{\textstyle\circ_{\mathrlap{\alpha_6}}}{\textstyle\vert}}{\circ}} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_4}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_5}}{\circ} && (3) \\
%
E_7 &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_3}}{\overset{\overset{\textstyle\circ_{\mathrlap{\alpha_7}}}{\textstyle\vert}}{\circ}} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_4}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_5}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_6}}{\circ} && (2) \\
%
E_8 &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_3}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_4}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_5}}{\overset{\overset{\textstyle\circ_{\mathrlap{\alpha_8}}}{\textstyle\vert}}{\circ}} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_6}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_7}}{\circ} && (1) \\
%
F_4 &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} \Rightarrow \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_3}}{\circ} - \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_4}}{\circ} && (1) \\
%
G_2 &&& \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_1}}{\circ} \Rrightarrow \underset{\mathclap{\alpha_2}}{\circ} && (1)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

I think that the vertical lines aren't spaced quite right (not central) and the vertical space introduced by the alphas on the higher dots should be removed (but I don't know how to do that).

Using this, you could reproduce all the diagrams except the second in **Aff 1**, and I'm not sure how to do the quadruple arrow in the first diagram in **Aff 2**.

However, if I were actually doing these diagrams, I would *definitely* use TikZ.

Comment: I actually poked at the TikZ side of this, and I still have no idea how to get the quadruple arrow.  It's surprisingly tough.

Comment: TikZ doesn't seem to have the capability of double/triple/quadruple arrows, does it?  Can they be implemented as new decorations?

Comment: Apart from the not entirely correct spacing of the vertical lines, they are too long in comparison to the horizontal ones.

Comment: @Pieter: did I claim it was perfect?  Seriously, changing the `\textstyle` to `\scriptstyle` ameliorates the size a little.

Comment: Unicode defines ⭆ U+2B46 RIGHTWARDS QUADRUPLE ARROW, so [insert usual text about `unicode-math`] @Matthew: double arrows: `\tikz[double equal sign distance]
\draw[double,thick,-implies](0,0.55ex) --++(3ex,0);` (see p.161 of the 2.10 manual)

Comment: @Caramdir: That works for double arrows, and for triple arrows if you include `postaction={-, thin, draw}`, but I couldn't figure out a way to generalize it to quadruple arrows.  I tried some sort of recursive `double, postaction={double, postaction={...}}`, but couldn't get it to work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you very much @Andrew. As for the quadruple arrow, looking at the book carefully, it might be that the publisher added lines *by hand* after TeX typesetting is done ...

Comment: @Antal: How about `\tikz \draw[postaction={double distance=0.3ex, -, draw, thin,shorten >=0.6ex},double distance=1ex,-implies](0,0.55ex) --++(3ex,0);`

Comment: @Caramdir: Oh hey, that works!  This is what comes of trying to generalize first and working examples second :)

Answer (score 3):

A first try, but I'm not capable of typesetting the quadruple arrow (as there is no symbol) or two nodes above each other. First I've defined a `\node{}{}` command ease of notation:

```
\newcommand\node[2]{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{\circ}}}
```

which then can be used as

```
\node{1}{a_0}-\node{2}{a_1}\Lleftarrow\node{1}{a_2}
\node{1}{a_0}\Leftarrow\node{1}{a_1}-\cdots-\node{1}{a_{l-1}}\Rightarrow\node{1}{a_l}
```

resulting in

[image: The rendering of two Dynkin diagrams]

Is this what you're looking for? If so, with some hacking it should be possible to get a quadruple arrow and a way to place nodes above each other. Maybe a `matrix of math nodes` in TikZ could be used for this, you try to emulate math spacing with minimal margins and you should be ready to go (if you want me to create a minimal example, I'll add one later). If I knew a way to draw a quadruple arrow :).

Comment: Thank you too! It's very nice and simple for linear diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version (3.141) of the `dynkin-diagrams` package gets pretty close to Kac's style.

[image: Kac style Dynkin diagrams][image: Kac style twisted Dynkin diagrams]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[Kac]{dynkin-diagrams}

\NewDocumentCommand\dyn{mom}
{\(\IfStrEq{#3}{}{#1_{n}}{#1_{#3}}^{\IfValueT{#2}{#2}}\) 
& \IfValueTF{#2}{\dynkin{#1}[#2]{#3}}{\dynkin{#1}{#3}} \\}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{tbl}{m}
{
\begin{figure}\caption{#1}\begin{tabular}{rl}
}
{
\end{tabular}\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tbl}{The Dynkin diagrams of the simple root systems}
\dyn{A}{}
\dyn{B}{}
\dyn{C}{}
\dyn{D}{}
\dyn{E}{6}
\dyn{E}{7}
\dyn{E}{8}
\dyn{F}{4}
\dyn{G}{2}
\end{tbl}
\begin{tbl}{The Dynkin diagrams of the extended simple root systems}
\dyn{A}[1]{1}
\dyn{A}[1]{}
\dyn{B}[1]{}
\dyn{C}[1]{}
\dyn{D}[1]{}
\dyn{E}[1]{6}
\dyn{E}[1]{7}
\dyn{E}[1]{8}
\dyn{F}[1]{4}
\dyn{G}[1]{2}
\end{tbl}
\begin{tbl}{The Dynkin diagrams of the twisted simple root systems}
\dyn{A}[2]{2}
\dyn{A}[2]{even}
\dyn{A}[2]{odd}
\dyn{D}[2]{}
\dyn{E}[2]{6}
\dyn{D}[3]{4}
\end{tbl}
\end{document}
```