# Tikz: Drawing an arrow with three lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently using tikz to draw an arrow with two lines using this style:

```
doublearrow/.style={draw, color=black!75, draw=black!50, thick, double distance=2pt, ->, >=stealth}}
```

The documentation does not say if it's possible to have an arrow with three lines. I've seen it in papers before and I guess it is probably also done with Tikz as the arrow tips are the same. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Found the answer: Draw an arrow path with a double line and at the same place draw a path with one line and voila - "triple" lined arrow.

 `triplearrow/.style={draw=black!75, color=black!75, thick, double distance=4pt, <-, >=stealth},`
 `thirdline/.style={draw=black!75, color=black!75, thick, <-, >=stealth}}`

Comment: It's a bit buried in the code, but the accepted answer to the following question contains code in TikZ for triple (and quadruple) arrows: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5309/86

Comment: @Tobias: Could you either post your solution as an answer and accept it or remove the question altogether. Otherwise it will spook around as unanswered forever.

Answer (score 3):

[Converting the OPs comment into an answer]

Found the answer: Draw an arrow path with a double line and at the same place draw a path with one line and voila - "triple" lined arrow.

```
triplearrow/.style={
  draw=black!75,
  color=black!75,
  thick,
  double distance=4pt, 
  <-, 
  >=stealth
},
thirdline/.style={
  draw=black!75,
  color=black!75,
  thick,
  <-,
  >=stealth
}
```